# R programming: cbind to specific column by column name

Tags: r

Suppose I have thousands of columns in "mydf". How can I `cbind` "new" column next to specific column name in "mydf". For example, I want to `cbind` it next to column "C" (by column name and not by number) and get the "Result".

mydf

```
A B C D
1 3 4 5 
1 3 3 2 
2 4 4 6
3 4 6 7
new
3
3
3
4
```

Result

```
A B C new D
1 3 4 3 5 
1 3 3 3 2 
2 4 4 3 6
3 4 6 4 7
```

Comment: I don't want to list all the column names as it not feasible, I just need to append next to specific column. The link is not helpful. There is no way I can keep track of column numbers as well. I just know the specific column name and I want to cbind next to that column and the order of the column could change all the time, I need to do it by column name

Comment: Search where is located your column to find the index.

Comment: I know I could do that by indexing, but is there any way I could append by name only?

Comment: What kind of data do you have where it is truly infeasible to list the column names? Regardless, if you know the first column and the interesting column, then try `dplyr` with something like `cbind(select(mydf, A:C), newcolumn=newvector, select(mydf, -(A:C)))`. See [here](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html#select-columns-with-select) for more info.